# overall code coverage for specific developers in TFS

Tags: tfs, code-coverage

I was just wondering if there was a way to analyse TFS, to figure out code coverage results against a specific developer.

Say I want to determine the code coverage statistics for one of the developers in my team.

Answer (score 3):

It’s not supported out of the box.

Don’t think it will be in the future, since its a very hard measurement:
   Developes write source code. Source code within a project is usually divided in    functionality not the developers. Code coverage results is the coverage of a given assembly being exercised in a testrun. We therefore need to analyse the coverage per code line and relate that code line back to a given developer changeset. Regardless of the unittest dll being instrumented, both the code in the unittest as the code being exercised is involved in the code coverage result. So which codeline being covered is counted for a specific developer ? The lines unittest, a line in a shared library, a line that was changed by 4 developers (is coverage shared), othes issues ?

But why are you asking this question, if you are trying to improve the quality of a specific individual code reviews and pair programming would be a more efficient approach. Even if it would be possible, terrorizing individuals on their code coverage would only result in dysfunctional measurement. Source code of a given product is shared in a Team, therefore the team is responsible for the coverage. Require your team to take that responsibility.

Comment: Conceptualy though this is straightforward.  One asks the configuration control tool to identify all lines of code modified by a developer; it arguably knows but this may not be easy to extract.  One asks the test coverage tool for all covered lines; it knows but this may not be easy to extract (undocumented?).  The intersection of these two is the coverage for that developer.  The size of the intersection divided by volume of code produced by the developer is his personal coverage ratio.

Comment: Even if you would do that... what would that measurement tell you ? If I put a statement in something that was already covered, my coverage increases... while I didn't test anything.

Comment: >One asks the test coverage tool for all covered lines; it knows but this may not be easy to extract (undocumented?). This function Can be done useing the CoverageInfo class in  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx